# jupyter notebook -> "To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:"

Tags: python, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open a specific notebook and the jupyter notebook get stuck with messages of the following type "To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:".
Other notebooks are working and running.
I tried to:

1. kill all processes and then reopen -> no change.
2. copy the directory to another place  -> no change.
3. copied the raw file that did not open and it worked ....

It seems to me that reason for all this mess is massive printing I've done in the file,
and jupyter "saving" the output of the notebooks where too large output cause this "To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:" with file not open issues

Comment: Does this help? https://groups.google.com/g/jupyter/c/9QatZmGVdx0

Comment: I tried this including playing with the config. It did not help. my guess is that this is a memory issue and not a browser one. Something internal to jupyter or something related to the interface of jupyter with chrome

Comment: Tried a different browser?

Comment: Nope, I just used the raw file. But I assume the same problem will resurface